# Where does Maven store junit jar files

Tags: maven, junit

I changed the version of junit from 3.8.1 to 4.11 in my pom file, when I ran maven it downloaded junit 4.11.  I got the message

"Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/junit/junit/4.11/junit-4.11.jar (245 kB at 825 kB/s)"

My tests ran fine after the install but I cannot find the jar file anywhere.  Can someone tell me where it is stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jar files that maven downloads by default can be found in:

Windows 10: `C:\Users\USERNAME\.m2\repository`

Unix/Mac OS: `~/.m2`

Comment: Ok thanks, i did a find using my git bash cmd(as admin) but I guess it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Assuming you're using git bash on windows using `cd ~/.m2/repository/` or `cd /c/Users/USERNAME/.m2/repository/` should put you in the maven repository directory.

Answer (score 1):

The default repo location could be changed. To show the actual repo location you can use this command:

```
$ mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=settings.localRepository | grep repository
/home/<username>/.m2/repository
```